# IO as a side-effect

Tags: haskell, io

Am I able to write a function executing `IO` as a side-effect of it? For example:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = putStr "text" >> return n*2
```

Obviously I don't have any way to write that code without it being completely incorrect, but that should at least show roughly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: You mean without the result type being `IO Int`?

Comment: Actually that's a perfectly fine function - it just has type `Int -> IO Int`, and that's a good thing. What's your issue with that?

Comment: Disallowing what you want is a *feature* of the `IO` monad. You can cheat with `unsafePerformIO`, but it won't do what you want here. Change the signature to `Int -> IO Int` and you'll be fine.

Comment: My not using IO Int wasn't indicative of wanting to disallow it, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function is almost right.  If it has a side effect then it needs type `IO`.  Also, function application binds tighter than infix.  Fixing these results in:

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
f n = putStr "text" >> return (n*2)
```

Comment: I was so close! Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: @Allan Welcome to StackOverflow! If Thomas's answer answers your question to your total satisfaction, then please *accept* it by clicking the checkmark to its left. And if you have not done so, please also *upvote* it by clicking the up-arrow to its left.

Comment: @dave4420 Upvoting requires 15 rep, the OP needs a few more upvotes him(her)self before (s)he can upvote.